# Image of the unit circle under inversion

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the image of any circle under any Mobius transform is a circle or a line, but I'm having trouble imagining what happens to the unit circle centred at 0 under the mapping $f(z)=1/z$. To me, it looks like you just get everything outside the unit circle.

Comment: $f(z) = z$ is just the identity transformation.  Perhaps you meant $1/z$?

Comment: Sorry, long day! I have edited it accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit circle is $\{e^{i t}, \, t\in [0, 2 \pi] \}$. Under $f(z) = 1/z$ it goes to  $\{e^{-i t}, \, t\in [0, 2 \pi] \}$, i.e., itself.

Comment: Cool thanks, and where would the unit disk go?

Comment: The unit disk just has a factor $r \in [0, 1]$, which goes to a factor $r' \in [1, \infty]$, i.e., it goes to the complement of the disk.